# Test my custom AOSP Android OS on real Hardware

Tags: android, testing, operating-system, android-source

Can I test my AOSP built (Custom Os) on redmi5a phone (rooted)? And How (Explaination will be appreciated) ? Does it requires some specific built?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Android build for a specific device includes a huge amount of modifications by SOC vendor and OEM (OEM is Xiaomi in your case).

AOSP is a general SW project. And every device model has a different HW.
OEMs integrate SoC and board-specific SW drivers and configs into AOSP to make it run on a particular device.

Most probably you can't get access to the device-specific parts.
So the simple answer is: you can't make this kind of test.

[AOSP vs Android](https://www.androidauthority.com/aosp-explained-1093505/):

> The AOSP contains everything developers need to build Android but it doesn’t include everything you need for a finished smartphone. First, Google and the AOSP can’t provide kernel device drivers for every hardware configuration out there. By device driver, we mean the firmware required for a phone’s hardware, such as the processor or cameras. Phone and SoC manufacturers, such as Qualcomm and Samsung, have to incorporate these drivers into their Android build. This is partly why updates take time to trickle down from AOSP to the smartphone in your hand.